# filter list with nested loop: if first loop finish successfully, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-loops

It might be a silly question but i really cannot wrap my head around it.
I'm implementing a filter, which is made by select input and it should select divs with given value saved in data-* attribute.

I do so with a nested loop: I first loop through all divs and then i list through all given values coming from select inputs.
If even one value from the select doesn't mach, i move on to the next div.
If it does, i move on to the next value of the select inputs values's array.
I almost get there, i miss the last little step which is: 
When i'm done looping all the values from the select and they all match with my div's data attr, then i should show this div.
I cannot get where i should put the code to show this div!

Here my (simplify) code. Please no comment about how i could just use javascript, i know it could work perfectly too but i cannot with this project so it has to be in jQuery.

html:

```
<select class="filter">
  <option value="01">1</option>
  <option value="02">2</option>
  <option value="03">3</option>
</select>

<select class="filter">
  <option value="jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="feb">feb</option>
  <option value="march">march</option>
</select>

<div class="list-item" data-day="01" data-month="jan">01 jan </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="02" data-month="feb">02 feb </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="03" data-month="jan">03 jan </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="02" data-month="march">02 march </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="03" data-month="jan"> 03 jan</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function combinedFilters() {
  var valuesArray = [];
  var items = jQuery('.list-item');

  jQuery('select').each(function() {
    valuesArray.push(jQuery(this).val());
  });

  console.log(valuesArray);

  jQuery(items).each(function(i, item) {

    if (jQuery(this).data('month') && jQuery(this).data('day') ) {
      var month = jQuery(this).data('month');
      var day = jQuery(this).data('day').toString();

      jQuery.each(valuesArray, function(i, value) {
        if (value != null) {
        console.log(value);

          if (value == month || value == day) {
            return true; // keep looping into values Array
          } else {
            return false; //go out of the Values loop to the next div
          }
        }
        //jQuery(this).show();
        console.log('show the div');
      });
    }

  });
}


function trigger() {
  jQuery('select').change(function() {

    jQuery('.list-item').hide();
    combinedFilters();

  });
}

jQuery('.list-item').hide();
trigger();
```

And here a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2x5yc9g/1/

Any suggestion with explanation is really appreciated!

**UPDATE**:

Based on the solution proposed by @Michal Młoźniak i fix my filters, if anyone is interested in the final result here is the whole code:
https://codepen.io/designbygio/pen/NRxvWo

Comment: so you want only `div`s with both filters displayed?

Comment: I feel like a better way to do this is to take the data selected from your drop downs and put that into 1 div, and then show that div. If you are just going to show the same data any way then you don't have to do all the work of filtering it out when it can be dynamic. I may be missing some piece that would suggest the way your doing it to be more efficient however.

Comment: @depperm yes, that's correct

Comment: @Turk unfrotunately the real list i have is generated by the php.. i might still do in the way you suggest (and it was my very first idea for the project) but is an old project and we don't want to spend too much time refactoring everything :/

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense I hope you figure it out then. I would type out a much longer answer to help  with your specific case but it seems like you have some decent answers posted already. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will that work for you or do you really need to have nested loop?

```
function combinedFilters() {
  var valuesArray = [];
  var items = jQuery('.list-item');

  jQuery('select').each(function() {
    valuesArray.push(jQuery(this).val());
  });

  items.each(function(i, item) {
    if (jQuery(item).data('month') === valuesArray[1] && jQuery(item).data('day') === valuesArray[0] ) {
      jQuery(item).show();
    }
  });
}

function trigger() {
  jQuery('select').change(function() {

  jQuery('.list-item').hide();
    combinedFilters();
  });
}

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.list-item').hide();
  trigger();
});
```

Comment: No i don't need to use a nested loop. Your solutions make sense and is more readable then the nested loop for sure. The only problem is that some values could be "null", i then need to check it they are or not which make the if more longer and unreadable.. but it probably will work!

Comment: At the end i used your solution and just add another level of check for the data attribute like month === valuesArray[1] || valuesArray[1] === null

Answer (score 1):

In order to show only the div with the data-day and data-month corresponding to the values selected in the first and second select tags a fast way could be:

```js
jQuery('select').change(function() {
  jQuery('.list-item').hide();
  var day = jQuery('select:eq(0)').val();
  var month = jQuery('select:eq(1)').val();
  $('.list-item[data-day="' + day + '"][data-month="' + month + '"]').show();

  // for inverted values, if they are
  $('.list-item[data-day="' + month + '"][data-month="' + day + '"]').show();
});
jQuery('.list-item').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="filter">
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
</select>

<select class="filter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="feb">feb</option>
    <option value="march">march</option>
</select>

<div class="list-item" data-day="01" data-month="jan">01 jan </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="02" data-month="feb">02 feb </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="03" data-month="jan">03 jan </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="02" data-month="march">02 march </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="03" data-month="jan"> 03 jan</div>
```

***UPDATE***

According to the comment:

> the null value means the filter wasn't selected so in your example if user select "1" and don't select "month" i should see all the divs with data-day=1 and don't care about data-month

The new snippet is:

```js
jQuery('select').change(function() {
  jQuery('.list-item').hide();
  var day = jQuery('select:eq(0)').val();
  var month = jQuery('select:eq(1)').val();
  $('.list-item').filter(function(i, e) {
    var lDay = $(this).data('day');
    var lMonth = $(this).data('month');

    if ((day.length == 0 || day == lDay) && (month.length == 0 || month == lMonth)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }).show();
});
jQuery('.list-item').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="filter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
</select>

<select class="filter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="feb">feb</option>
    <option value="march">march</option>
</select>

<div class="list-item" data-day="01" data-month="jan">01 jan </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="02" data-month="feb">02 feb </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="03" data-month="jan">03 jan </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="02" data-month="march">02 march </div>
<div class="list-item" data-day="03" data-month="jan"> 03 jan</div>
```

Comment: That actually look clean and nice! Is just taking everything from different prospective :) I still have the problem with null value (from select) tho..

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta If some select values are null there is no problem. I added a null month and the change event works. If you refers to other, please let me know.

Comment: the null value means the filter wasn't selected so in your example if user select "1" and don't select "month" i should see all the divs with data-day=1 and don't care about data-month. Instead now i don't see any divs because i have no divs with data-day=1 and data-month=null.
does this explain better what i try to achieve?

Comment: At the end the first solution worked good for me but i'm still interested to know if there is a good way to check for null value here so i can use much shorter way (if you happy to do it :) )

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta Answer updated with a new snippet. Let me know if it works fine for you. Thank you so much.